# Is WhatsApp main window single activity with multiple fragments?

Tags: android

Just want to experiment on a beginners app design (I just started to study Android development)
I was wondering if the main screen of WhatsApp is just a single activity with multuple fragments:

(the CHATS, STATUS, and CALLS are all in 1 activity?)

[image: WhatsApp main window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is true. It contains `tab layout` with different fragment in each tab.